# Adding a Progress View to a Search Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uiprogressview

I would like to add a progress view within my search bar, to show how much content from the search has loaded.

Here is my progress view so far in my **Storyboard**:

[image]

However, with different languages, the `"cancel"` button changes width, as seen here:

[image]

This therefore makes my `ProgressView` not reach the edge of the search bar. Is there an easier way to do this, or is there a way to get the size of the `SearchBar`'s text field?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask**

Comment: You can make the custom searchBar. Take a UIView and put all the necessary items like, TextField and below that put a ProgressView and add the button, by pressing which you can do the searching functionality and thus can manage it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, I had an idea. The search bar, like many other types of **views**, have **subviews**. So all I had to do was access the correct subview so I could get its width.

Here was my code:

```
progressView.frame.width = searchBar!.subviews[0].subviews[1].frame.width - 10
```

Comment: can i add progressview in searchbar bottom programatically ?

Comment: What do you mean? So the progress view is on the straight edge of the whole search bar?

Comment: @ViraniVivek Not too sure, but you may be able to use `addSubview` on one of the search bar subviews. Use trial and error to find it (by colour to find the right one), or you may be able to find something else online.

Comment: @ViraniVivek I stopped this project a while ago, so I have not done anything with this search bar.

Comment: @ViraniVivek Did you manage to solve it by adding a subview? If you couldn’t, I may create a project to test if it works or not

Comment: i'm still working but no solution can you help e for create like this.?

Comment: @ViraniVivek Ok, I’ll try making one when I get home at about 3:30 after school (GMT). That will be in ~8 hours, sorry ☹️